# getting error when trying "git push heroku master"

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

Following railstutorial.org, and I'm getting this error when I try to push to heroku:

```
# git push heroku master
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (68/68), done.
Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 87.95 KiB, done.
Total 85 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.3
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       You have modified your Gemfile in development but did not check
       the resulting snapshot (Gemfile.lock) into version control
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * sqlite3-ruby (= 1.3.2)       
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * sqlite3-ruby
       FAILED: http://docs.heroku.com/bundler
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ bundle install
$ git add Gemfile
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -m "Make Gemfile and Gemfile.lock consistent with each other."
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hi Justice - thanks for the edits, but I'm still getting the error. I received some other suggestions to a "bundle install" and I realized I'm getting a permission denied error when it tries to install: "Installing sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:519:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/API_CHANGES.rdoc (Errno::EACCES)" -- thanks again.

Comment: Either use RVM, which lets you have a Ruby installation particular to your user and therefore lets you install gems without requiring `sudo`, or use `sudo bundle install`.